# How often is it polite to ask for a story-identification

Tags: discussion, story-identification, asking-questions

I asked for a [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/150995/sci-fi-book-about-a-male-entering-a-competition-that-he-wins-and-gets-recruited) and it went big. I gained 113 rep in just 2 days. I have another story-identification question but don't want to look like a rep-farmer who just only asks and answers questions that should get large amounts of rep. How often if it polite to post story-identification questions that have the chance of going big. My question even became a Hot Network Question so I really need help.

Comment: The answers below are good, but if you feel you ask _that many_ story identification questions in such a short space of time that you're worried about it, perhaps that's a red flag? Maybe spend more time performing your own research before resorting to asking for help. Then you may post fewer questions, or at least they will be slowed down. And you won't have to worry about looking suspicious or impolite.

Comment: That being said, looking at your profile, you've only asked two. So, yeah. Carry on :) (I once saw someone asking more like four or five per day, for several weeks, and _that_ comes across as impolite.)

Comment: @lightnessracesinorbit yeah I didn't know if that was too many

Comment: @ChristopherPeart:   Well, to be honest, if you keep asking [tag:story-identification] questions from not that long ago, then either you are very forgetful or you actually are a "rep-farmer".    If you legitimately have [tag:story-identification] questions, it's one thing, but I hope you are not just asking [tag:story-identification] questions just for the sake of asking questions because you think it's a puzzle for people or you are trying to farm rep.

Comment: @ThePopMachine all story-id my questions are from books at least 7 years ago. I am not going to be a "rep-farmer". I only ask for real reasons. I have only asked 2 questions for a story-id. As a new member a am especially trying to avoid doing that or even looking like a rep-farmer. I am treading on thin ice. Right now I am getting ready to ask another question but not a story-id. I even have a +2 question that has no answers and is not a story-id. So it should be pretty clear I am not trying to re-farm. Also I don't want to waste others time by posting questions I know the answer to and not a

Comment: ...answering myself. Trying to keep a positive question rate though.

Comment: @ChristopherPeart:   It's no problem.   You're fine, and frankly you're worrying too much.   I'm just adding that if you really were just trying to rep-farm, that is probably frowned upon.

Comment: @ThePopMachine Ok! Thanks.

Comment: @ChristopherPeart, I should add:  I, myself, primarily ask questions more than answering them.   But I'm asking questions which I think will have answers that will be interesting to people (including myself) and to which I don't know the answer.    Asking question to which you *do* know the answer too often (sometimes is okay, if it's *very* interesting) starts to look like gaming the system.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Ask them as often as you want. Asking a high volume of *good quality* questions is not only allowed but encouraged. Good content is what these sites thrive on.

However, you may *want* to slow down your pace, for a couple of reasons:

1. If you ask too many too fast, some of them may get lost in the shuffle. After seeing 5 or 6 of them, users may decide they've seen enough. This is particularly true with story-id, as there's a much smaller subset of our users that handle them.
2. The reputation cap. You can only get 200 reputation points in a single day. For questions, that amounts to 40 upvotes, which is a lot of *one* question, but spread over many, you could easily reach it. If you pace yourself more, you are less likely to hit it.
3. Badges. Asking good questions on multiple days is one of the things Stack Exchanges rewards as good behavior by giving out badges, if you're into that kind of thing.

Comment: Yea I was about to ask another Story-ID but may hit the rep-cap as I just got 173 rep today.  Well if it calms down I will post it tomorrow

Comment: Another reason to ask questions on separate days is that you'll get the [Curious](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges/122/curious)/Inquisitive/Socratic badges sooner.

Comment: Since you mention badges, is it worth editing to add that there are some vary lucrative badges to be had by hitting the rep cap a lot

Answer (score 10):

One every day should be fine.

The quality of the question matters more than the frequency. Make sure you include all details, respond to comments.

Welcome to the Stack! You've been off to a good start.

Comment: Thanks! I am glad to be off to a good start

Comment: Yea, just don't use "Need help identifying a story/TV show/book/movie/anime" as the title. There are way too many of these generically titled questions on the site.